# type of class in python

Tags: python, class, types, new-style-class

why if I do:

```
class C(): pass
type(C())
```

I got: `<type 'instance'>`, but if I do:

```
class C(object): pass
type(c())
```

I got: `<class '__main__.c'>` ?

The first is not very userfull

Comment: What do you want to have instead? What is not useful? That it is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up the difference between old-style and new-style classes. The former are the default, and the latter inherit explicitly from object.

All old-style objects were implemented with the built-in type instance. The fact that they are still the default and their type remains 'instance' is a result of retro-compatibility precautions.

This is extracted from the Python docs (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

> 3.3. New-style and classic classes Classes and instances come in two
> flavors: old-style (or classic) and
> new-style.
>
> Up to Python 2.1, old-style classes
> were the only flavour available to the
> user. The concept of (old-style) class
> is unrelated to the concept of type:
> if `x` is an instance of an old-style
> class, then `x.__class__` designates the
> class of `x`, but `type(x)` is always
> `<type 'instance'>`. This reflects the
> fact that all old-style instances,
> independently of their class, are
> implemented with a single built-in
> type, called instance.
>
> New-style classes were introduced in
> Python 2.2 to unify classes and types.
> A new-style class is neither more nor
> less than a user-defined type. If `x` is
> an instance of a new-style class, then
> `type(x)` is typically the same as
> `x.__class__` (although this is not
> guaranteed - a new-style class
> instance is permitted to override the
> value returned for `x.__class__`).
>
> The major motivation for introducing
> new-style classes is to provide a
> unified object model with a full
> meta-model. It also has a number of
> practical benefits, like the ability
> to subclass most built-in types, or
> the introduction of “descriptors”,
> which enable computed properties.
>
> For compatibility reasons, classes are
> still old-style by default. New-style
> classes are created by specifying
> another new-style class (i.e. a type)
> as a parent class, or the “top-level
> type” object if no other parent is
> needed. The behaviour of new-style
> classes differs from that of old-style
> classes in a number of important
> details in addition to what `type()`
> returns. Some of these changes are
> fundamental to the new object model,
> like the way special methods are
> invoked. Others are “fixes” that could
> not be implemented before for
> compatibility concerns, like the
> method resolution order in case of
> multiple inheritance.
>
> While this manual aims to provide
> comprehensive coverage of Python’s
> class mechanics, it may still be
> lacking in some areas when it comes to
> its coverage of new-style classes.
> Please see
> http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/
> for sources of additional information.
>
> Old-style classes are removed in
> Python 3.0, leaving only the semantics
> of new-style classes.of new-style classes.

Comment: you need to edit your answer and change all your "x.__class__" into "`\`x.__class__\``"